# VBS looping simple query

Tags: vbscript

helo please help this is the code

```
Option Explicit

Dim iim1, i, s , shell
dim iret
dim myname, mypath
dim pos


'initialize iMacros instance
set iim1= CreateObject ("iMacros")

'i = iim1.iimOpen ("-fx", false) 'Use open Firefox instance if available
i = iim1.iimOpen ("-fx", true) 'Always open new instance

pos = 2

Do while pos < 10

iret = iim1.iimSet("loopVar",Cstr(pos))
iret = iim1.iimPlay("ecc2.iim")

set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
shell.Run "%comspec% /c C:\Users\SDFL\Desktop\dc1.bat"

pos = pos + 1
loop
```

After the line

```
iret = iim1.iimPlay("ecc2.iim")
```

I want it to check if `iret < 0`. If yes then I want it to repeat the step

```
iret = iim1.iimSet("loopVar",Cstr(pos))
iret = iim1.iimPlay("ecc2.iim")
```

in a loop until `iret > 0` with same `Pos` value without disturbing the main loop, and if `iret > 0` I want it to move it to the next lines of the code.

So this is a loop inside a loop how to do that? Please take care of `Pos` value, e.g. if `Pos` value was 6 when `iret < 0`, then repeat the step with `pos = 6`, if `iret > 0` then move forward to next lines of code, so in last step `pos = 7` and the whole code proceeds.

I hope you get it

Please give the code  thanks

***ADDED***

```
 >>pos = 2

iret = iim1.iimSet("loopVar",Cstr(pos))
iret = iim1.iimPlay("ecc2.iim")

Do

iret = iim1.iimSet("loopVar",Cstr(pos))
iret = iim1.iimPlay("ecc2.iim")
iret = Rnd() > .5
WScript.Echo pos, CStr(iret)
Loop Until iret


set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
shell.Run "%comspec% /c C:\Users\SDFL\Desktop\dc1.bat"

pos = pos + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an inner loop, just add an inner loop:

```
pos = 2

Do while pos < 10
  Do
    iret = iim1.iimSet("loopVar",Cstr(pos))
    iret = iim1.iimPlay("ecc2.iim")
  Loop Until iret > 0

  set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
  shell.Run "%comspec% /c C:\Users\SDFL\Desktop\dc1.bat"

  pos = pos + 1
loop
```

Of course, since your outer loop is simply iterating over a sequence of numbers, you'd be better off using a `For` loop for that. And I'd move the creation of the `WScript.Shell` object outside the loop, so you don't waste system resources (re-)creating the object over and over again.

```
set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")

For pos = 2 To 9
  Do
    iret = iim1.iimSet("loopVar",Cstr(pos))
    iret = iim1.iimPlay("ecc2.iim")
  Loop Until iret > 0

  shell.Run "%comspec% /c C:\Users\SDFL\Desktop\dc1.bat"
Next
```

Comment: ahh thats it thank you sir it worked perfectly .. and thank you Ekkehard.Horner sir for helping ,

Comment: sir 1 more simple thing i want to ask about inner loop is , that it will loop endlessly until iret > 0 , what if i want to loop it only 5 times not more than that ? whats the code ? means if it does not get iret > 0 after 5 inner loops/times it should continue to the next lines of code ?? once again thanks for your reply, i am grateful to you

Comment: Add a counter variable that you increment with each cycle of the inner loop and change the condition to `iret > 0 Or counter > 5`.

Answer (score 0):

The method of choice for looping over a numerical range is `For`, not `While`:

```
>> For pos = 2 To 9
>>     WScript.Echo "pos", pos
>> Next
>>
pos 2
pos 3
pos 4
pos 5
pos 6
pos 7
pos 8
pos 9
```

To repeat an action at least once and until some condition is fullfilled, use `Do ... Loop Until`:

```
>> For pos = 2 To 9
>>     Do
>>        ret = Rnd() > .5
>>        WScript.Echo pos, CStr(ret)
>>     Loop Until ret
>> Next
>>
2 True
3 True
4 True
5 False
5 False
5 True
6 False
6 True
7 True
8 True
9 False
9 False
9 True
```

There should probably an upper limit (counter/timer?) on the `Do` loop to aviod endless loopings.

**Added:**

In my sample, the loop controlling boolean variable `ret` is set to `True` (= please stop looping) if the function `Rnd()` returns a value > .5. Given a function `.iimSet()` that returns some number indicating success or failure you surely can work out for yourself what number (..-1, 0, +1 ..) to compare how (=, <, >, <=, >=) with that return value to stop the looping in case of success. Hint: double check your tests "iret < 0" vs. "iret > 0" wrt `.iimSet()` delivering 0.

Comment: thank you sir for your reply but the code ain't working with iret = iim1.iimSet("loopVar",Cstr(pos))
iret = iim1.iimPlay("ecc2.iim") can you please provide the code with these , i am new to vbs . these are scripts of imacros

Comment: ok sir tried with above code and added to first post, the code works 1 time then gives a popup 2 true i click ok and then it stops , the ret returns value - 933 . i want it to continue continuously without popup . in trying for this to work i had to remove "loop" from last line of original code , so now please tell the code to loop the whole code in addition to the secondary ret loop . thank you